# How to plot family of functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

[image]

I need to plot this function for `A = 7,8,9,10` in the scale seen in the above image, for these values:

```
k_1 = 683.037971206
k_2 = 1.96604876786e-4
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Matlab has many resources that you can study. Your question is much too general.